# Windows based containers on google cloud run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to understand what containers are supported by google cloud run.

One place in its key features are:
https://cloud.google.com/run/?hl=sr#all-features

> "Any language, any library, any binary Use the programming language of
> your choice, any language or operating system libraries, or even bring
> your own binaries."

In another place, it says:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract

> Supported languages and images
>
> Your container image can run code written in the programming language
> of your choice and use any base image, provided that it respects the
> constraints listed in this page.
>
> Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit.
> Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.

I am really confused.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, Cloud Run doesn't support Windows images, it only supports Linux based containers, but Google [Kubernetes Engine (GKE)now has support for windows](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/how-to-deploy-a-windows-container-on-google-kubernetes-engine) docker based containers.

Google offers a codelab in 2 parts ([part1 GCE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-windows-containers-computeengine/#0) |[part2 GKE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-windows-containers-kubernetesengine/#0)) to create windows docker containers and to use it on Compute engine (GCE) and GKE, these are the only 2 GCP products that supports windows docker images.

The main idea is create a Docker image, push this to Google Container registry and use this to create a GKE infrastructure using windows images.

Answer (score 1):

The container is 64-bit Linux container. You can create any container that is compatible with that ABI. Within that container, you can do whatever you like, as long as it adheres to the container runtime contract.